# is there a good rough formula for estimating svg file size?

Tags: file, svg, graphics

is there a good rough formula for estimating svg file size based on the number and type of shapes it contains?  For example, let's say you have an svg with 10 circles and 20 paths.  Could you estimate something like a circle generally adds 2-3kb of size and each path adds 1-2kb of size?  So basically if you had to do some quick and dirty math on the fly you could say for 10 circles and 20 paths I would estimate a file size of:

([10*2kb] + [1*20kb]) = 40kb

?

Comment: No, it doesn´t really work like that. A path for example could be extremely short, or huge. Maybe if you explained your use case, someone may be able to give some hints.

Comment: I'd like to be able to explain the impact (or lack of impact) of adding an object graph of 10 circles with 20 paths to an existing svg.  If I simply add 10 basic circles and 20 basic paths to an empty svg then the total file size is only 2kb so the impact to file load time in this scenario would be minimal.  In what scenario would a path need to be huge?  Also, the file size and load time would be small for the scenario I described but are there any other factors I should consider?  For example, how do you account/estimate for impact to rendering time/quality?

Comment: Take a case of an svg which contains outlines of the states of the u.s vs 50 paths which are just rects. Malcolm Mclean mentioned path segments as a way to calculate which could be useful. Load time will be affected by file size and I guess interactions with the DOM. For rendering probably consider the amount of fill as well. But there's lots of other stuff, what transforms are applied, how many points, how much fill, how many dom elements etc. So I don't think you will be able to get a simple answer, other than more DOM nodes slower to render, more fill slower, larger file slower to load.

Answer (score 0):

Generally complex geometry will be stored as Bezier paths, which in SVG are represented in the form M123.0,456.0,C456.0,798.0,222,0,333.0,444.0,555.0 ...

That will account for the bulk of the data. And it's six reals of probably 6 digits each (but check precision) per path segment. So I make that 40 or so bytes per path segment, then add a bit for the path overhead, then a bit more for the styling data.

That should give you a ballpark.